# How to call function that change my total value Typescript code

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, calculator

I want to change automatically my total when I change quantity or price.

I try to use this code, but nothing happens.

My products are: `this.products = this.ps.getProduct();`

```
     this.form= this.fb.group({
          'total': new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.nullValidator]),
           'products': this.fb.array([
          ]),
        });
```

This is my function that calculate  `Total = p.Unit_price * p.Quantity;`

```
totalFunc() {
    let Total = 0;
    for (let p of this.products) {
        Total = p.Unit_price * p.Quantity;
    }
    return Total;
}
```

Now this function I want to display in html code, and for this I use ng-change

```
<form [formGroup]="form" >
<tr formArrayName="products" class="group" style="cursor: pointer" *ngFor="let item of products; index as i" [formGroupName]="i">
<td>
<input formControlName="Unit_price" [value]="(item.Unit_price)"  type="number" />
</td>
<td>
<input formControlName="Quantity" [value]="(item.Quantity)"  type="number" />
</td>
<td>
<input formControlName="Subtotal" [value]="(item.Subtotal)" ng-change="totalFunc()" readonly type="number" />
</td>
</tr>
<form>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to update the `Subtotal` according to the changes made in `Unit_price` as well as `Quantity`, isn't it? If so the so the `totalFunc()` method should call in `ng-change` event of those text boxes. That means the code for `Unit_price` will be `<input formControlName="Unit_price" [value]="(item.Unit_price)" ng-change="totalFunc()" type="number" />` The modified code should be like the following:

```
<tr formArrayName="products" class="group" style="cursor: pointer" *ngFor="let item of products; index as i" [formGroupName]="i">
    <td>
        <input formControlName="Unit_price" [value]="(item.Unit_price)" ng-change="totalFunc()" type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input formControlName="Quantity" [value]="(item.Quantity)" ng-change="totalFunc()" type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input formControlName="Subtotal" [value]="(item.Subtotal)"  readonly type="number" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you! I change it, my method "totalFunc()" not executed when I change Unit_price or Quantity

Comment: Is that method directly accessible? or you need to access through controller name/alias?

Comment: This is method directly access. How to access? Sorry, I don't understand well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this life cycle hook method

```
ngOnChange(){
     //Update your total in this area
}
```

This event will get triggered on every change in input fields of the current view

Comment: ngOnChange(){     let Total = 0;    for (let p of this.products) {      Total += p.Unit_price * p.Quantity;      }            return Total;}  and in html: ng-change="ngOnChange()"   ??

Comment: Partially correct, since this is a angular hook, we no need to call this method from html. This method will get triggered on changes of input fields

Comment: Yes, but nothing change. My total doesn't change.

Comment: Why you r not using ngModal to get text box values in ts ??

Comment: In ts, how?  I try something  like this in html, but not function <input formControlName="Unit_price" [value]="(item.Unit_price)" [(ngModel)]="item.Unit_price"  type="number" />